# kendo grid filter does not work with nested property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've got a grid

```
    @(Html.Kendo()
          .Grid<Entity>()
          .Columns(column =>
              {
                  column.Bound(i => i.Date);
                  column.Bound(i => i.User.FirstName);
          })
      .DataSource(data => data.Ajax()
                              .ServerOperation(true)
                              .Read(read => read.Action("index", "app")))
   )
```

but in case filtering by firstname, gets filter property **Member = "undefined"**

any ideas how to figure it out?